# What is wrong with Angular's logical OR in option attribute? When [(ngModel)] is used in select the [selected] attribute doesn't affect the selection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template, angular-template-variable

I have an option in select like this:

```
<option [selected]=" impulse === 10 || isTraining " value="10">10</option>
```

When I have any possible value of `impulse` and `isTraining` is `true` my expectation is that the current option will be selected by default due to selected keyword in the dropdown, but it isn't. Are logical operators ever evaluated for the attributes required a boolean value?

The full select here is

```
<select class="form-control" name="flashFormatImpulse" id="field_flashFormatImpulses"
                            (change)="handleFlashImpulseSelection($event)" [(ngModel)]="impulseSelection" [disabled]="isStarted">
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 1" value="1">1</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 2" value="2">2</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 3" value="3">3</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 4" value="4">4</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 5" value="5">5</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 6" value="6">6</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 7" value="7">7</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 8" value="8">8</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 9" value="9">9</option>
                        <option [selected]="impulse === 10 || isTraining" value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
```

UPD

[image]

that is for code below:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="businesslogic.flashs.flashcard.impulse"
                           for="field_flashFormatImpulses">Flash Impulse</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="flashFormatImpulse" id="field_flashFormatImpulses"
                            (change)="handleFlashImpulseSelection($event)" [(ngModel)]="impulseSelection" [disabled]="isStarted">
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 1" value="1">1</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 2" value="2">2</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 3" value="3">3</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 4" value="4">4</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 5" value="5">5</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 6" value="6">6</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 7" value="7">7</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 8" value="8">8</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 9" value="9">9</option>
                        <option [selected]="impulse === 10 || isTraining" value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option [selected]="true" value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

and the effect is still the same when we change the code to

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="businesslogic.flashs.flashcard.impulse"
                           for="field_flashFormatImpulses">Flash Impulse</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="flashFormatImpulse" id="field_flashFormatImpulses"
                            (change)="handleFlashImpulseSelection($event)" [(ngModel)]="impulseSelection" [disabled]="isStarted">
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 1" value="1">1</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 2" value="2">2</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 3" value="3">3</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 4" value="4">4</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 5" value="5">5</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 6" value="6">6</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 7" value="7">7</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 8" value="8">8</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 9" value="9">9</option>
                        <option [selected]="true" value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option [selected]="true" value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

i.e. having the same `[selected]` for both (but a different look).

I.e. `<option [selected]="true" value="10">10</option>` works and `<option [selected]="impulse === 10 || isTraining" value="10">10</option>` is not

UPD 2

[image]

That's how it looks for code below:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="businesslogic.flashs.flashcard.impulse"
                           for="field_flashFormatImpulses">Flash Impulse</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="flashFormatImpulse" [(ngModel)]="impulseSelection" id="field_flashFormatImpulses"
                            (change)="handleFlashImpulseSelection($event)"  [disabled]="isStarted">
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 1" value="1">1</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 2" value="2">2</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 3" value="3">3</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 4" value="4">4</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 5" value="5">5</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 6" value="6">6</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 7" value="7">7</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 8" value="8">8</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 9" value="9">9</option>
                        <option [selected]="impulse === 10 || isTraining" value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" >
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 3" value="3">9</option>
                        <option *ngIf="!isTraining" [selected]="impulse === 9" value="9">9</option>
                        <option [selected]="impulse === 10 || isTraining" value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>impulse {{impulse}}, isTraining {{isTraining}}, result: {{impulse === 10 || isTraining}}</div>

                <select class="form-control">
                    <option [selected]="impulse === 10 || isTraining" value="10">10</option>
                </select>
```

The problem with selection correlates with using the `[(ngModel)]="impulseSelection"` for the selector (that is a binding for value, used on the controller side) and is initialized as

```
impulseSelection = 3;
```

So the associated binding is always overriding the value of the selector to 3 while it is not present there. It looks like the only solution is to force this `impulseSelection` value to 10 when `isTraining` is assigned to true.

Comment: what you have written looks fine. it's likely a result of the rest of your code. replace "impulse === 10 || isTraining" with "true" and see if its working. most likely you have several options set to true at the same time

Comment: as written, there's no point in adding "|| isTraining" because when isTraining is true, it will be the only option available.

Comment: @Rick I've tried with this `<option [selected]="true" value="10">10</option>` and still have option not selected by default...

Comment: @Rick I'd like it not only be the only option, but also selected by default with no need to select if from the initially empty dropdown for the better user experience.

Comment: right. there's no reason why that shouldn't work. check your console for javascript errors

Comment: @Rick please see my question updated; that's related to the model binding for the selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no reason why that should not be working. Check your logs for javascript errors. If none start with and empty select statement and build it back to what you have, one piece at a time until you find the problem.

I also like to add the values to the html just to be sure they are what you think they are. like this:

```
<div>impulse {{impulse}}, isTraining {{isTraining}}, result: {{impulse === 10 || isTraining}}</div>

<select class="form-control">
  <option [selected]="impulse === 10 || isTraining" value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: added more intriguing data to the question; still see no console errors

Comment: sure. <option [selected]="impulse === 10 || isTraining" value="10">10</option> is not working while <option [selected]="true" value="10">10</option> is working

Comment: I'm still not sure what "not working' means if you have only one option it should show by default. try console logging impulse && isTraining. maybe they aren't what you think they are? its also possible they are both undefined at some point?

Comment: you may see how the only option can't be selected at the screenshot attached to the question. It is just not selected by default and it is possible to leave the select control not selected for any value.

Comment: I edited my code above. try that and see if the values are what you think they are.

Comment: @Rich please see my question updated; that's related to the model binding for the selector.